# Color code agenda view per file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have several .org files, e.g. personal.org and work.org.

When viewing the agenda, I'd like to have events from each file differently colored.

For example,

```
Wednesday  12 June 2013
  personal:   11:00am........ Personal Meeting
  work:       2:00pm- 3:00pm  Work Meeting
```

There are already some colors in the agenda, but those two lines are both white. How can I set the line coming from personal to one color, and the line coming from work to another? I figure at least there has to be a way to define a color scheme based on the `personal:` and `work:` text if there's no easy way to have org do it by file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I found as solution for what you ask, you have to use a hook function, changing faces after the agenda view is ready. The following code is untested, but should get you going:

```
(add-hook 'org-finalize-agenda-hook
    (lambda ()
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward "personal:" nil t) 
          (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (point-at-eol)
             '(face secondary-selection)))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward "work:" nil t) 
          (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (point-at-eol)
             '(face bold))))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just changing `face bold` to `face (:foreground "green")` did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

John Wiegley sent once a patch he wrote so that, with an :OVERLAY: property, all Work items have the same background color. And with another value for Personal, those items have a different color.

See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/54342

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work, I've added `:OVERLAY: (face (:foreground "green"))` as he has, but it doesn't appear to have any impact on the agenda - any ideas?

Comment: @Josh that thread contains a patch which you probably didn't apply.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar I see a patch inline in his email, but it doesn't implement :OVERLAY:?